# What does attributeRestrictions mean in Openshift Container platform object schema definition?

Tags: openshift

```
apiVersion:
kind:
spec:
status:
  evaluationError:
  rules:
  - apiGroups:
    attributeRestrictions:
      Raw:
    nonResourceURLs:
    resourceNames:
    resources:
    verbs:
```